# How do I sequence the date in Google sheets without sequencing the year?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to sequence dates for the beginning of the week.  It should read:

```
21-12-2015
28-12-2015
04-01-2016
```

and so on.  My problem is that when I highlight the first two dates and drag; I get

```
21-12-2015
28-12-2015
21-12-2016
28-12-2016
```

and so on.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me.

First, I just put in some dates. (Since I'm in the U.S., I used the usual date format of m/d/yyyy):

[image: step 1]

Then, I created a custom date format to be dd-mm-yyyy:

[image: custom date format day-month-year]

Then, I simply highlighted the first two dates and dragged down the autofill handle, and I got what you'd expect:

[image: after autofill]

I think what's happening in your case is that Google Sheets isn't recognizing your dates as dates and instead it's treating your data like a formatted number.

Answer (score 1):

To drag-and-drop a sequence reliably, you need to select at least three values to start with.

If you only choose two, then the system cannot know if you mean a sequence of pairs (value1, value2), or a continuously increasing sequence (value1, value2, value3=value2+difference, etc).